# Delete empty blob directory

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I want to delete some blob directory using Azure Java SDK (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblobdirectory?view=azure-java-legacy). Storage account is ADLS Gen2.

I know the concept that to delete directory I need to delete all blobs "inside" it but still - even if I delete all blobs, in Azure Storage Explorer I can see empty directories, and I want to get rid of them also.

I have tried such code and it works great but I'm stuck when it comes to delete empty blob directory:

```
val storageAccountName = "<account-name>"
val containerName = "<container-name>"
val sas = "<sas>"
val path = "copyTest/testDirectory"

val container: CloudBlobContainer = CloudStorageAccount
  .parse(s"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=${storageAccountName};SharedAccessSignature=${sas};EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net")
  .createCloudBlobClient().getContainerReference(containerName)


def deleteBlobs(blobs: Iterable[ListBlobItem]): Unit = {
  for (blob <- blobs) {
    blob match {
      case blockBlob: CloudBlockBlob => {
        logger.info("blob")
        logger.info(blockBlob.getUri.getPath)
        blockBlob.delete()
      }
      case blobDirectory: CloudBlobDirectory => {
        if (blobDirectory.listBlobs.iterator().hasNext) {
          logger.info("blobDirectory not empty")
          logger.info(blobDirectory.getUri.getPath)
          val blobsFromDir = container.listBlobs(blobDirectory.getUri.getPath.replace(containerName + "/", ""))
          import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._
          deleteBlobs(blobsFromDir.asScala)
        } else {
          logger.info("blobDirectoryEmpty")
          logger.info(blobDirectory.getUri.getPath)
          
//           blobDirectory.delete() #1
//           blob.delete() #2
//           val targetDirectory = container.getBlockBlobReference(
blobDirectory.getUri.getPath.replaceFirst(destContainerName + "/", "").substring(1)) #3
//          val targetDirectory = destContainer.getDirectoryReference(
blobDirectory.getUri.getPath.replaceFirst(destContainerName + "/", "").substring(1)) #4
//          targetDirectory.delete()
        }
      }
      case _ => logger.info(s"Unknown blob type")
    }
  }
}

import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._
val blobs = container.listBlobs(path).asScala
deleteBlobs(blobs)
```

I get response:

#1
[image]

#2
[image]

#3

[image]

#4
[image]

**Any ideas how can improve my function?**

Comment: `in Azure Storage Explorer I can see empty directories` - Could this be because Azure Storage Explorer is caching the data? Check for the same in Azure Portal and see if you are seeing the empty directory there.

Comment: using listBlobs() shows empty directories with type: `com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlobDirectory`

Comment: What kind of storage account is it? General purpose storage account or ADLS Gen2?

Comment: right, post is missing this information - it's ADLS Gen2

Comment: Aah, that explains it. You will need to use ADLS Gen2 specific SDK instead of Blob Storage SDK to delete a folder.

Comment: can you provide link to docs or some snippet, please?

Comment: Added answer with more details. HTH.

Comment: thank you! I have one more question regarding this issue - I have usedBlobStorage SDK to easily move blobs between storage account (using .startCopy method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblob?view=azure-java-legacy#com-microsoft-azure-storage-blob-cloudblob-startcopy(final-uri)). what would be equivalent approach using this ADLS Gen2 SDK? I don't see proper method in DataLakeFileClient to be honest... maybe `rename` method properly parametrized?

Comment: I am also not able to find it. May be use Blob Storage SDK for that purpose? ADLS Gen2 Storage Accounts are built on top of Blob Storage so most of the operations available in Blob Storage should be available in ADLS Gen2 account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your Storage Account is ADLS Gen2, you cannot use Blob Storage SDK to delete folders as the folders in your General Purpose Storage accounts are virtual folders (they are simply blob prefixes).

In order to delete the folders, you would want to use SDK specific for ADLS Gen2 accounts. The SDK you would want to use is [`com.azure:azure-storage-file-datalake`](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.azure/azure-storage-file-datalake).

You can find more details about using the SDK and some code samples here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-java.